# Print a div in the right side of the paper

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, printing

So i'm trying to print a div on the right side of the paper but, when I pressed Ctrl+P on google chrome, the result on the print preview, the div is on the left side.

I'm using bootstrap. I tried this

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6"></div>

<div id="printMe" class="col-md-6">Print this text on the right</div>
</div>
```

but still when I print, the text is on the left side of the paper.

Comment: try adding "&nbsp;" into the empty div..

Comment: add pull-right class

Comment: see @media print https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the left part of the page is empty. Try this:

```
<div class="row">
<div id="printMe" class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-6">Print this text on the right</div>
</div>
```

Reference: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting

Comment: It's kinda weird, offset-6 is not working but when I used pull-right, it works

Comment: what's your screen resolution? you must have at least 992px width of screen in order for the 'md' to work.

for the pull-right, yes it works but that beats the responsive feature. well, it's for printing anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-6"></div>

<div id="printMe" class="col-md-6">Print this text on the right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit, i'm currently on mobile so I didn't know how to display code propperly

Comment: I believe your answer is correct but it doesnt. It only works with pull-right not with offset. thanks for the answer tho.

Answer (score 0):

Its kinda weird that offset is not working here.

its works with

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6"></div>

<div id="printMe" class="col-md-6 pull-right">Print this text on the right</div>
</div>
```

Thanks guys btw.